# import selenium from selenium import webdriver driver = webdriver.Chrome("G:\\Web Development learn\\Jarvis\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe")

Tags: selenium

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62713/devtools/browser/1fd74cf7-ae95-4df9-a3ae-eb4863b52823
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\exp_5.py", line 4, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("G:\Web Development learn\Jarvis\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
File "C:\Users\local_q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in **init**
RemoteWebDriver.**init**(
File "C:\Users\local_q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Users\local_q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "C:\Users\local_q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\local_q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86
Current browser version is 85.0.4183.121 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Comment: As indicated in you error: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86 Current browser version is 85.0.4183.121 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe .Either update your chrome or download version 85 of chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your browser version first.Browser version is updating time to to time you need to use exact driver version.[Here you can download drivers](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
according to to your browser version . for example if you are using chrome browser 85.100.03.02 then you need to use chrome driver exe version should be 85